# How to separate into groups the next string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Assuming a textarea has the following content(a string), Which regular expression could be useful to split on groups?

```
GET /bar
{
  "limit":  {
     "foo": 1
   }
}

GET /barfoo
{
  "limit": {
     "foo": 1
   }
}

GET /fuzz
{
  "limit": 1
}
```

What I meant when a group is the next output:

```
GET /fuzz
{
  "limit": 1
}
```

I've tried the next regex without success:

```
((GET|PUT|POST|DELETE).*\n{\n(.*\n)+}\n)
```

Comment: I’ll try it thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant `s.split(/[\r\n]+(?=(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)\b)/)`. However, it should work even without `\b` unless you have lines starting with those values but not equal to them.

Comment: No luck with that regex but thanks!

Comment: It [seems working](https://jsfiddle.net/8xob15m1/). [Another code demo with the same regex](https://jsfiddle.net/nswwmoxq/). Please show your *exact code*.

Comment: Mmmm now I've see something wrong with my string format but tried with the raw and seems to work, only need some adjustments, if finally it works I'll put this as the answer given by you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a splitting approach if your string only consists of these blocks:

```
s.split(/[\r\n]+(?=(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)\b)/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDpg97/1/).

**Details**

- `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more CR or/and LF symbols
- `(?=(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed by `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` or `DELETE` whole words (since `\b` is a word boundary).

Since the lookahead is a non-consuming pattern, i.e. the text it matches is not added to the match value buffer, the ALLCAPS words still get into the resulting output.

```js
var rx = /[\r\n]+(?=(?:GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)\b)/gm;
var str = 'GET /bar\n{\n  "limit":  {\n     "foo": 1\n   }\n}\n\n\nGET /barfoo\n{\n  "limit": {\n     "foo": 1\n\n   }\n}\n\nGET /fuzz\n{\n  "limit": 1\n}';
var result = str.split(rx);
console.log(result);
```